# Is it possible to open empty html popup with JS in it?

Tags: javascript, html, popup

So we can do:

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>JavaScript Popup Example 3</title>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function exitpop()
{
    my_window = window.open("", "mywindow1", "status=1,width=350,height=150");
    //my_window.document.write('somehow add JS'); 
    my_window.document.write('<h1>Popup Test!</h1><br/>'); 
    my_window.document.write('J_\alpha(x) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m! \, \Gamma(m + \alpha + 1)}{\left({\frac{x}{2}}\right)}^{2 m + \alpha} ');
}
</script>

<body onunload="javascript: exitpop()" >
<h1>JavaScript Popup Example 4</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

but how to for example add to header of that html page with something like `<script type="text/javascript" src="path-to-MathJax/MathJax.js"></script>` to enable MathML and tex formulas rendering?

Comment: Don't put `javascript:` in onsomething handlers...

Answer (score 3):

Yep, you just need to concatenate the script tags, like so: [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/4MxAD/2/)

The money-shot code sample is:

```
jswin = window.open("", "jswin", "width=350,height=150");
jswin.document.write("Here's your popup!");
jswin.document.write('<scr'+'ipt>alert("Here\'s your alert()!");</scr'+'ipt>');
```

Comment: Doesn't the blank window.open URL parameter break the [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) on IE browsers?

Comment: @RobertoLinares: I'm not sure but I tested this in IE9 without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript to create a node named script, and sets it's attributes with javascript. Then append the node to document.head.

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>JavaScript Popup Example 3</title>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function exitpop()
{
    var my_window = window.open("", "mywindow1", "status=1,width=350,height=150");


    var head = my_window.document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0);
    alert(head.innerHTML);
      var script = my_window.document.createElement ("script");  
      script.src = "a.js";  
      head.appendChild (script);
    alert(head.innerHTML);
}
</script>

<body onunload="javascript: exitpop()" >
<h1>JavaScript Popup Example 4</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry, when i finish my demo, I found that you can't use document.write.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using an iframe, you can set its head and body altogether, and you can put it in the window.